# Why do 1st order low-pass filters on a square wave look like this?

Tags: filter, low-pass, square

[image]

I know that low-pass filters only allow voltages at low frequencies to go through the circuit and block out voltages that come in at high frequencies. With this in mind, how does the graph display this since the frequency of square waves are nearly infinite (aka why does the graph look the way that it does)?

Comment: Do you have the transfer function or the circuit schematic for the low-pass filter? If so please post it in your question.

Answer (score 4):

What you're observing is not actually a filter not working. It's working perfectly. First, a little bit about filter to make sure we're on the same page about it, and then I'll explain why what you observe is expected.

**1.** About filter:

The concept of "RC low-pass filter allows certain frequencies through and removes other frequencies" is not entirely correct. It is handy for general abstraction and approximation of how things work in certain situations.

In reality, there is such thing as "attenuation".

Look at a graph from [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html) article:

[image]

The filter removes certain portion of the signal of that frequency, different for every frequency. Low frequencies are untouched, but around the "knee" at low-pass filter's frequency, higher frequency signal loses more and more the higher you go. It's not immediate cut-off.

Capacitors have different impedance for different frequencies. They don't pass DC through, but as you go higher in frequency, they pass the stuff through better and better. So for lower frequencies, there is a huge impedance of the capacitor to the ground in the RC (pretty much no connection to ground), while for high frequencies of the very same signal it's basically a short circuit to the ground, so higher frequencies are effectively grounded. For frequencies around cut-off frequency, there is a partial effect.

Something like: for 1Hz signal RC is a voltage divider of R and 1 GigaOhm, for near cut-off you have a voltage divider of R and R (capacitor has impedance for that frequency that is equal to R), and for high frequencies the same circuit is a voltage divider of R and 0.001 Ohm.

In real life inductance of capacitors starts to dominate at even higher frequencies, but it's beyond the scope of this discussion. Just bear in mind that it exists.

Anyway, the point is, it's not like 100kHz low-pass filter lets everything under 100kHz through, but 101kHz signal disappears.

However, in your situation you're observing a different phenomenon than you think you are.

---

**2.** About why what you're observing makes sense and why filter is actually working perfectly:

In your situation it's important to say that yes, that switch from low to high is a very high frequency signal (it's not immediate, but very quick), which should be - and actually *is* attenuated. You don't see a spike on the other side immediately, like you would if high frequency just passed through.

What you're observing instead is a DC at Vlow=0 and DC at Vhigh=5V. It's basically an RC-circuit. You're doing nothing else but charging the capacitor through the resistor with DC. Of course it can't stay at 0V forever, you're applying 5V **DC**(!!!) to it. DC passes through without a problem and charges the capacitor. Yes, the filter removes all high frequencies, but it doesn't remove DC.

Your square wave has high frequency only when switching from 0V to 5V and from 5V to 0V. And those spikes are perfectly filtered out - output doesn't spike after switching! But after switching you have flat voltage line - DC. DC passes through. Square wave frequency is **not** the same as a signal frequency. Signal frequencies are the frequencies of the sine waves of different degrees of "compressed-ness" that make up the resulting signal.

Make sure you examine good sources which cover this properly and in greater detail, it's not very complicated. I'm trying to simplify things because I don't feel like writing a whole book chapter. But I hope this gives some intuitive understanding of what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A single RC circuit does not automatically convert a square wave into a sine wave.  It's a gradual process.

Rearranging the capacitor equation \$Ic=C dV/dt \$ for delta V in increments of delta t to include Ohm's Law for the series resistor \$V/I=R\$, since they share the same current , we get the partial derivative of voltage;

- \$dV/dt=V/RC\$  We call RC=T for a DC step or square voltage change, the exponential time constant to show the initial slope of voltage change as it charges towards the target voltage.

A square wave of f=1/2t for 2 equal but opposite pulses per cycle can now be compared with the exponential time constant T=RC to [observe the significance.](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgDCBMCmC0AcICMYB0kxkgdmwZjHkgDYBOU7EPAVhFuomriSQCgA3ZbYkUnpblUjgoyTJjoiIaaqwBOXHnmF48S4YzCsAxlTVC9PPlNTjMSELCSpsSSAOzVSNPABYs8SmnOsA7ot4lfWMtTgF%20UmFw5EhECDwxcUlpcFRZBWi7RFV%20WJEGPwCkSMNkEq1dHJjs-WKNVLMwC1g0bAxSJ1JXaiQ8bEjnBqaOANjEaMhIVxELFCTaFLQkJ2XXLoJIwon4Gp4x8B1Syemq-elTM2brHAxCV1cyJGIGUiG2DMFjo6n8rXcEqzqZB2QJSAD6xFcYLAYKQrjUSHgYOo0IuTTBVlhrH%20lie1WBUXKIChkOhsPhxERYNcqHIdLpYGoeFI8DAeFR4iQGK5bBxEC%20WSgOxESNJMLhCKRKO85m5WJxeHgJ2EPWEISgEKhMIeLGRqMgcoNBrw2LZVCVyHudBBGDiIGwmrJ7nIYMgaX1hrBDpNCotU0YIII0wgKEd2rALrd0vQntDJqAA)

Here are 3 identical RC=T circuits and clocks of f=1kHz with different input wave forms.

Since a triangle is the integral of a square wave we expect it's source frequencies to decline with a slope. This helps with the RC circuit where current looks like the derivative and voltage like the integral so the output begins to look more like a sine wave.
[image]
Current is plotted in yellow on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

> *why does the graph look the way that it does*

I'm using a low-pass RC filter like this for my explanation: -

[image]

Image from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter).

Next, consider the fundamental capacitor formula \$Q = C \cdot V\$.

If we differentiate that formula to find the rate of change of charge (\$\frac{dq}{dt}\$), we derive capacitor current and, rate of change of voltage: -

$$I = C\cdot\dfrac{dV}{dt}$$

This tells us that if the capacitor current \$I\$ is held constant, the voltage across the capacitor rises at a linear rate of \$\frac{I}{C}\$. Of course, what you see in the RC filter is not a linearly rising capacitor voltage but a rising voltage that rises less as time progresses.

This **can only mean** that the capacitor current is reducing as time evolves.

So, when we first apply a sudden voltage (say 5 volts) to the input of the RC filter, the current that flows into the capacitor is determined by the voltage across the resistor; one side of the resistor is 5 volts and the other side of the resistor is at 0 volts. It's at 0 volts because the capacitor voltage is initially zero (being fully discharged).

That informs us what the current is (Ohm's law).

So, as the capacitor voltage ramps up, the voltage across the resistor reduces and, this causes the current that flows through the resistor (and into the capacitor) to reduce and hence, the rate at which voltage ramps up on the capacitor diminishes.

That's it in a nutshell.